# double variable type output is always 0

Tags: c++, c, double

For an assignment I have to create a "rock paper scissor lizard spock" game where I have to output the percentage of the winnings at the end. In the program I calculate the number of games player A and B have won including tie games, the total games played, and the win percentage of each player. All the variables are `int` except for the percentage which is a `double` variable type. When I calculate the percentage (games won / total games) I get a 0 as a result. Any ideas why? Sorry I could not provide any code, this is an assignment and I'm not allowed to post it anywhere online.

Comment: We really can't help without code. There could be a multitude of problems and we'd have no idea.

Answer (score 8):

Without seeing code I can't be 100% sure, but my guess is that you're dividing values like this:

```
int numWins   = /* ... */
int numLosses = /* ... */
double ratio = numWins / numLosses; // <-- Error!
```

In C and C++, that last line is a logic error.  Although you're storing the result as a `double`, because you're dividing two `int`s the division is done as integer division and then stored in a `double`.  C and C++ don't look at the type of the variable you're assigning to when deciding what division to use; the ratio of two `int`s is always computed using integer division.

To fix this, you can add a cast:

```
double ratio = (double)numWins / numLosses;
```

This casts `numWins` to a `double`, which ensures that the division is done as floating-point division because at least one of the operands is a `double`.  That should fix your issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 Definitely plausible.

Comment: +1. quick note about casting: (double) for C, or static_cast<double> for C++ in your case

Comment: i have tried it and it works just fine, thank you so much, now im ready to hand in my assignment

Answer (score 2):

In most programming languages, division between two integers is an integer. Thus, `5 / 10` will give `0`, as will `1 / 10` and `9 / 10`. This takes place *before* assignment to the result variable, so the fact that the result variable is a `double` is irrelevant. You need to turn either the divisor or the dividend into a double for the floating point calculation to kick in.